# Checking the type of a method generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, generator

I have a function that takes another function as an argument. I want it to check if the argument is a regular function or a generator.

```
import types

def my_func(other_func):
    if isinstance(other_func, types.GeneratorType):
        # do something
    elif isinstance(other_func, types.FunctionType):
        # do something else
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"other_func is of type {type(other_func)} which is not supported")
```

But the problem is that the function is a class method, so I get the following:

```
other_func is of type <class 'method'> which is not supported
```

The class method looks like this

```
MyClass:

    def other_func(self, items):
        for item in items:
            yield item
```

Is there any way I can check to see if the class method is a generator or a function?

Comment: What is your usecase to do something different with different type of function?

Comment: how you are calling your function my_func

Comment: I'm using it as a generic function call manager for an MPI-distributed task.

Comment: You should probably check the result of the function rather than the function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to use the `.__func__` hidden attribute as follows:

```
import types

def my_func(other_func):
    if isinstance(other_func.__func__(other_func.__self__), types.GeneratorType):
        # do something
    elif isinstance(other_func.__func__(other_func.__self__), types.FunctionType):
        # do something else
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"other_func is of type {type(other_func)} which is not supported")
```

This digs a little deeper into the function instead of just saying it is a class method.

Answer (score 1):

call your function:

```
c = MyClass() 
my_func(c.other_func([1,2,3]))
```

full code:

```
import types

def my_func(other_func):
    if isinstance(other_func, types.GeneratorType):
        # do something
        print ("test1")
    elif isinstance(other_func, types.FunctionType):
        # do something else
        print("test2")
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"other_func is of type {type(other_func)} which is not supported")


class MyClass:
    def other_func(self, items):
        for item in items:
            yield item

c = MyClass() // <------
my_func(c.other_func([1,2,3])) // <------
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to call the function. It's not the right answer for my code, but it set me on the right track to find it myself. +1

Comment: I'm glad I helped! :) @berkelem